# Ошибка в коде при множественном наследовании

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор, параметры, множественное-наследование

Правильно ли написан код для создания множественного наследования (класс `С` наследует классы `А` и `В`) и конструкторов с параметрами?

```
class A
{
    int Aa;
    int Ab;
  public:
    A(int Aa, int Bb) {};
};
class B
{
    int Ba;
    int Bb;
  public:
    B(int Ba, int Bb) {};
};

class C: public A, public B
{
    int C1;
    public C(int Aa, int Ab, int Ba, int Bb, int C1) : A(Aa,Ab) : B(Ba,Bb)
    {};
};
```

Comment: Все поля остаются неинициализированными.

Comment: @VTT но это же конструктор с параметрами. при создании обьекта пользователь сам вводит значения. или в этом ошибка?

Comment: Ну а введенные пользователем значения никак не используются.

Comment: "Ошибка в коде" - никогда (слышите? Никогда!) не указывайте, в чем состоит "ошибка". Для нас угадывать Ваши ошибки - это развлечение, а Вам, очевидно, не особенно нужен ответ.

Comment: @Igor пишет что двусмысленность Aa  и Bb в строчке где конструктор для класса С

Comment: Там должна быть запятая между вызовами конструкторов предков, а не двоеточие.

Comment: @Igor не решает проблему все равно

Comment: @Igor помогло спасибо!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чуть подправьте:

```
class C: public A, public B
{
    int C1;

public:

    C(int Aa, int Ab, int Ba, int Bb, int C1 )
    : A(Aa, Ab), B(Ba, Bb), C1(C1)
    {};

};
```

Ну, и соответственно исправьте конструкторы `A` и `B` - чтоб они поля инициализировали:

```
class A {

    int Aa;
    int Ab;

public:
    A(int Aa, int Ab):Aa(Aa),Ab(Ab) {};

};

class B {

    int Ba;
    int Bb;

public:
    B(int Ba, int Bb):Ba(Ba),Bb(Bb) {};

};
```

Comment: Спасибо Harry! Ваши подсказки всегда очень аккуратные и дельные и всегда помогают! спасибо большое!